# Regex to ignore multiple prefixes and match only if they dont have one or two specific hardcoded attributes?

Tags: regex, go, regex-lookarounds

I am looking for a GoLang RE2 regex that would only not match if the user types in one of the following, all of these must not be case sensitive :

`.i l`
`.i Latest`
`.info l`
`.info Latest`
`p!i l`
`p!i latest`
`p!info l`
`p!info latest`

So in each of these cases, theres one prefix and one attribute to it, if the user types in just the prefix without the `latest` or `l` after it or types in anything else other than `latest` and `l` after the prefix including any numbers or special characters. It should be a match.

I have jerry rigged this regex :
`(?i)\A\.i (?:L.|[^L]+L)`

This regex somewhat works, but it only works for `.i` prefix and checks for an `L` in front and does not check for numbers.
I cannot wrap my head around how i could solve this.
I wouldnt mind using multiple regexes, one for each prefix. I tried replacing the `\.i` with other prefixes and the `(?:L.|[^L]+L)` part with the word `LATEST`. That does not seem to work.

Thanks for the help : )

Comment: Maybe `(?i)^(?!(?:\.|p!)i(?:nfo)? l).*`? See https://regex101.com/r/KcWMpa/1/

Comment: doesent this match everything other than the prefixes and their attributes?
i am looking for a check where it matches the prefix only if theres no attributes or if there is an attribute after it its either `l` or `latest` otherwise its a match

Comment: Perhaps like this `(?i)^(?:\.|p!)i(?:nfo)?\b(?!\s+l(?:atest)?\b).*` https://regex101.com/r/1itPzl/1

Comment: i am so sorry, i apologize, the regex engine i am using is GoLang RE2 engine. Explains why none of these were working. i edited the post and added that in.

Comment: You can first match what you don't want, and then capture in group 1 what you want to keep `(?i)^(?:(?:\.|p!)i(?:nfo)?\b(?: +l(?:atest)?\b).*|((?:\.|p!)i(?:nfo)?\b.*))`  https://regex101.com/r/hfzD6j/1

Comment: this one categorizes everything that i dont want matched in group 0 perfectly. The problem is, i am working with a discord bot which has limited functionality. It only allows me to trigger an action on a regex match and does not allow anything beyond that. I am not really big on glang or regex myself. Would there be any way to exclude everything in group 0 from being a match?

Comment: Wouldn't it be way easier to use a `switch` or `if` for that? Or how using an inverted regex `\.i l|\.i Latest|\.info l|...` that checks if the input is something that shouldn't be matched?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go does not supports lookarounds. In that case, you can specify what you would allow to match.

In this case you allow any of the prefixes optionally followed by a "word" other than "l" or "latest"

One option could be

```
(?i)^(?:\.|p!)i(?:nfo)?\b(?:(?: +(?:la(?:t(?:e(?:s(?:t\S)?)?)?)?)| +(?:[^\sl]\S*|l[^\sa]\S*|la[^\st]\S*|lat[^\se]\S*|late[^\ss]\S*|lates[^\st]|latest\S+))(?: +.*)?)?$
```

In parts

- `(?i)` Case insensitive modifier
- `^` Start of string
- `(?:\.|p!)i` Match `.i` or `p!i`
- `(?:nfo)?\b` Optionally match `nfo` followed by a word boundary
- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `(?:` Non capture group

    - `+(?:la(?:t(?:e(?:s(?:t\S)?)?)?)?)` Match 1+ spaces and `la` `lat` `late` `lates` or `latest` *(followed by at least a single non whitespace char for latest)*
    - `|` Or
    - `+(?:[^\sl]\S*|l[^\sa]\S*|la[^\st]\S*|lat[^\se]\S*|late[^\ss]\S*|lates[^\st]|latest\S+)` Match 1+ spaces followed by 6 variations that can start the same word excluding 1 char (also excluding a whitespace char using `\s`), or match the word followed by at least a single whitespace char
  - `)` Close non capture group
  - `(?: +.*)?` Optionally match 1+ spaces and 0+ times any char except a newline
- `)?` Close non capture group and make it optional
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/HU7Kgl/1)